# Best Method for Creating a P&L in Google Sheets from Database?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, pivot-table, finance

**Objective: Create a Profit & Loss ("P&L") report in Google Sheets across multiple properties.**

I have a database of income, expense, debt service etc. for different properties. Call this sheet DB1:

[image]

If I create a pivot table from this data in the format I want, it looks like this:

[image]

I want to insert calculated rows in between rows in the pivot table above. For example, I want to insert a row for Net Operating Income ("NOI") which is equal to Income - OpEx. And I want one for Cash Flow ("CF") which is equal to NOI - Other Expense - Debt Service.

**Problem 1: There appears to be no way to insert a calculated ROW in a pivot table in Google Sheets.**

**Workaround 1:** The workaround I'm using (thank you @horanimal and @TheMaster) is to create a second database table, "DB2", with calculated row entries:

[image]

This utilizes named functions. In the example formula cell below, it's using a named function `CY_PROPERTY()` which indirectly grabs the property name from the property column in the given row and a named function `NOI` which totals the income and expense for Property A from the DB1 tab using `SUMIFS` functions and takes the difference.

Now we can make a third database, "MasterDB", which combines DB1 and DB2 via an array, and make the pivot table from it that we want, with calculation rows such as NOI added:

[image]

This method of using pivot tables is ideal because it allows us to add accounts (e.g. Misc Income), create additional reports such as reports comparing the prior year ("PY") to the current year ("CY"), change views etc.

**Question 1: Is this the best method to achieve our objective?**

Next, another problem arises when we want to add new properties. If we add financial data for a new Property C to DB1, we also need to add the set of formula rows for Property C to DB2.

**Problem 2: Can you call functions in Google Sheets and evaluate them in the target cell?**

We couldn't find a way to do this. So instead, we made a formula template generator at the top of the DB2 sheet. You enter the new property name, e.g. Property C in all rows of the template, and then copy and paste it into the DB2 database below it:
[image]

Because all named functions use indirect references to inputs instead of cell references, it works.

**Question 2: Is there a better way to create DB2 entries for new properties?**

In conclusion, the above methodology doesn't seem to be the cleanest solution, and it still seems like there should be a way to insert calculated rows in pivot tables, but this is what we've got.

Comment: Tried named functions?

Comment: It would be good to understand the motivation for wanting to 'store' formulas like this - I suspect this might be an XY problem?

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to create a bunch of **Named Functions** ([best tutorial I've seen](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/named-functions/) *shout out to Ben Collins, my guru!* & [official docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12504534?hl=en) *shout out to Google!*) instead of the separate sheet of formulas you mentioned.

Then you can write an `=IF()` function in the `A` column rows that evaluates the fixed inputs in the other columns of the same row you mentioned & calls whichever function you want based on the logic you set.

For example, you could have a custom function called `ADDONE()` where the formula definition is `=INDIRECT("R[0]C[1]",FALSE)+1` and then include that in your if function.

Here's an example I made real quick to illustrate:
[Custom Named Functions being called in other functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atTa7.png)

Comment: Hello! Thank @horanimal and @TheMaster! This is an incredible suggestion! I had never heard of named functions before. This definitely provides 90% of the solution and allows me to make a much cleaner `IF` statement to evaluate the different named functions based on the criteria of that row.

Comment: Cont'd: Is there a way to make a "menu" of these functions, and `VLOOKUP`  to call them based on the criteria in a given row? I will have about 10 functions total, and while it's definitely doable, that's quite a lengthy `IF` statement that could be prone to errors. Even with the named function in a given cell, when I reference it from another cell, it grabs whatever value is in the originating cell instead of executing it in the new cell.

Comment: @TheMaster @horanimal I just added an example in my original question at the bottom of why I would like a "formula menu" instead of an `IF` statement if possible. Thank you again!

Comment: @KimHopkins thanks for the extra context/example! This is a fun one to problem-solve. What you’re trying to do is definitely possible—you just may need to adjust your approach to accomplish it. Question: would the IF statement be any longer if you call the named functions directly vs doing a VLOOKUP to grab them? Or how do you imagine that part working?

Comment: Hi! Just give me One more day! I'm trying to give you some context on what I was trying to do and the workaround I did using your named functions suggestion. I thought it would be better to have the full context!

Comment: Oh no rush—just wanted to make sure we didn’t leave you hanging without a solution! Glad to hear you’ve got a workaround & excited to see what the clever solve ended up being :)

Comment: Hello! I updated the post to explain what I'm actually trying to do. I know it's long (sorry) but I really tried to keep it as clear as possible to give you context of the objective in case there is a better way. Thank you!

Comment: @KimHopkins thanks for updating! This is super helpful and I think I'll be able to help you out—just need to take a closer look before I respond. If you're able to share a copy of that spreadsheet I'd be happy to add some formulas for you to look at directly in there as well before updating the answer here, just to confirm they work.

Comment: @KimHopkins I think you nailed it! **There’s another approach where you kinda make your own pivot table instead of relying on the built-in tool, but it would require manual changes whenever added a new account/line item (it would however handle new properties no problem—let me know if you’re curious to see that method)** Your solution may not be the cleanest as you said but sounds like it’s getting you your desired outcome—nice work and glad the names functions were a nudge in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks @horanimal! Got it. I think I'll stick with this for now as I want the functionality of the pivot table to auto update with new accounts etc. Good to know though that there isn't an obvious workaround that I missed!